# Insert into specific row in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to insert a new entry into a specific row in an sqlite database in android. The basic idea is that the database stores entries like this:

```
id   day        time
1   Monday     09:00
2   Monday     11:00
3   Tuesday    10:00
```

the ID column is auto incremented. The idea is that if you wanted to insert a new entry of "Monday 10:00" it should be inserted into the database at id 2, and the other entries would update accordingly i.e. the entry "Monday 11:00" would become id 3 etc.

In short, is there any way to insert data into a specific row? If there is, will it automatically change the other entries?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no. Auto increment means you don't control the field.

Comment: So basically it's going to be a case of getting all the entries, sorting them, then reinserting? Thanks for reply

Comment: Pretty much, maybe you should remove the auto-incerement property.

Comment: Why do you absolutely want the data to be sorted in the database ? In my opinion, it doesn't matter how the data is sorted in the DB the important is to show sorted rows.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be sorted in the database, just means I have to rethink the method I have for removing items, as it stands atm, its just a case of getting ID from a list view and removing that ID. Thanks for replies, least I have an idea now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change a certain row in a table, you can use [UPDATE](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

[INSERT INTO](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is for adding new rows.