# Rearrange the database row after deleting?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a database in my app and when I perform a delete operation with a database row ID, the row item will get deleted but my table keeps that empty row. How can I remove this?

**Database Class:**

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact1.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact1";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";
    public static final  String UID="_id";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact1" +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }
    public void deleteContact(String d,int pos){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, UID + "= ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos)}); 
    }
}
```

When I perform the `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, UID + "= ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos)});` operation in `deleteContact(String d,int pos)`, the table keeps a record of the empty row. How can I rearrange the table with the _id column sequential?

Comment: So if I have rows 1, 2, 3 and I delete 2, then you have 1, 3 and you would like these to get rearranged automatically to 1, 2, correct? If that's the case, try this after `db.delete`, `db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " set " + UID + " = (" + UID + "-1) where " + UID + " > " + String.valueOf(pos));`. It's not a nice solution by any means but it worked when I tested it.

Comment: @DanielK this will work fine but the problem is when i add new item in table   _id starts counting with last entered value. explanation :  I have rows 1, 2, 3 and I delete 2, then i have 1, 3 by using your query it will sort but when i add new item it starts with 4,5,6......

Comment: You could remove the `autoincrement` from the table declaration, then every time you insert, you could query for the total rows & then insert at `_id+1`. Again, it's at workaround at best.

Comment: @DanielK is there any way to Achive these thing without removing autoincrement ?

Comment: Not from what I've read so far. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067610/how-to-rearrange-table-after-deleting-first-row-in-sqlite) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928105/insert-into-specific-row-in-android-sqlite-database#9928143).

Comment: @DanielK thanks for help